# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First and One-to-Many mapping problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first

I have problem with mapping existing database.

2 tables (simplified)

```
"SomeEntity"
Id int
Name nvarchar
```

and

```
"EntityProperty"
EntityId int
Name nvarchar
```

and have relation one-to-many from Entity to entity properties.

How I can map this using EF 4.1 Code First?

Thx in advance.

**Edited 1:**

ok) this is my code

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var context = new DataContext();

            var result = context.SomeEntity.Include(p => p.EntityProperties);

            foreach (var entity in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entity);
            }

        }
    }

    public class SomeEntity
    {
        public int EntityId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<EntityProperty> EntityProperties { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Id: {0}, Name: {1}", EntityId, Name);
        }
    }

    public class EntityProperty
    {
        public int EntityId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SomeEntity> SomeEntity { get { return this.Set<SomeEntity>(); } }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>().ToTable("SomeEntity");
            modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>().HasKey(k => k.EntityId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<EntityProperty>().ToTable("EntityProperty");
            modelBuilder.Entity<EntityProperty>().HasKey(k => k.EntityId);
        }
    }
```

Problem when I use Include in query for get properties:

Invalid column name 'SomeEntity_EntityId'.
Invalid column name 'SomeEntity_EntityId'.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Id` instead of `EntityId` at your `SomeEntity` class? Change mapping to that too.

Comment: With Id I have the same exception, but with some different message
Invalid column name 'SomeEntity_Id'.
Invalid column name 'SomeEntity_Id'.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try that if you didn't make it work while I was sleeping :)

Comment: So, nHibernate can map this ("bag") for reading, but can't insert new item. Btw I'll add PK to tables and and this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem.
I cannot add simple PK to relational table. I added complex PK on all unique fields and map one-to-many. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int SomeEntityId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<EntityProperty> EntityProperties {get;set;}
}

public class EntityProperty
{
    public int EntityPropertyId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Creating that ICollection (at '1' side of relation) should be enough to set 1:N relation. It will create SomeEntity_Id (or SomeEntityId) column in EntityProperty table.

Edit: Btw: You can set that collection to virtual, if you want lazy loading enabled.

```
public virtual ICollection<EntityProperty> EntityProperties {get;set}
```

Edit:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class EntityProperty
{
    // What is PK here? Something like:
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    // EntityId is FK
    public int EntityId {get;set;}

    // Navigation property
    [ForeignKey("EntityId")]
    public SomeEntity LinkedEntity {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

First try this.. then you can add that ICollection again, I didn't include it this time to keep it simple (and you an still query properties.. but with: `context.EntityProperties.Where(x=>x.EntityId == X);`)

Comment: I think it's also going to need [Column("EntitiyId")] on EntityPropertyId

Comment: It won't. When you name your PK like `<entityname>Id`, it's automatically mapped as a PK thanks to conventions. Edit: Hmm.. maybe I am wrong... dunno why you want to add that annotation? To rename column? Then you are right I guess :)

Comment: It wasn't the PK aspect I was thinking about, it was that the column in the existing EntityProperty table is apparently called "EntityId" - will EF cope with that too?

Comment: No, you are right, I just edited my comment, sorry for mistification. I misunderstood it.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't generate new DB. I must use existing, with structure from my first post.

Comment: Your class have primary key, but in my DB, table EntityProperty without PK. And it is problem in this case.